# I want to find the index/ or position of the word that my program found to be the longest in the string

Tags: c#, string

This is my code, I am taking input from user, I want to find out the index/ or position of the longest word in the string the user is typing. I can't seem to figure this out!
Wherever I try to find help, I get indexOf() method in which you manually have to type the word of which you are trying to find index.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Question1
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   
    Console.WriteLine("Enter String:");
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] words = line.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string word = "";
    int ctr = 0 , len, max = 0;
    
    foreach (String s in words)
    {
        if (s.Length > ctr)
        {
            word = s;
            ctr = s.Length;
           

        }

    }
    Console.WriteLine("Longest String : " + word);
    Console.WriteLine("Length : " + ctr);

}
 }
```

Comment: Note that prefixing lines with `>` is used to indicate that you are quoting someone/something. You should now use that for your own words. What are you trying to do with `IndexOf`? At the moment you are searching for the string word within the string word (it will be at position 0) but you're explicitly starting the search from the position indicated by `ctr`, which will be the length of the word according to your code above. So you're saying "does the string `word` contain the string `word` after the end of the string `word`?"

Comment: Oh, my bad I didn't know. I'll be careful next time! Thanks for noticing!

Comment: It seems likely that you want to search `line` for `word`, not `word` for `word`.

Comment: Actually, I'm finding the longest string and the length of that string from the user input, but I can't seem to figure out how to find the position of that specific string. Ignore the last line indicating indexOf, I forgot to remvoe that line!

Comment: `IndexOf` would be perfect for finding the position though.

Comment: Could you elaborate it a little bit? like what should I write in my code to find position of the longest word I found! I can't seem to solve this.

Comment: Try [this overload of `IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-6.0#system-string-indexof(system-string)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the index of the word you've found like this:

```
int indexOfWord = line.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
```

So if the word is the first word, `indexOfWord` will be 0. If it's "William" in "Hello William", then it will be 6, etc.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/DZQF48778)

Comment: thankyou so much this worked just fine for me!!! <3

Answer (score 2):

To find longest word index from a sentence you have to use `.indexOf()` method from `Array` class.

Instead of

```
Console.WriteLine(word.IndexOf(word, ctr));
```

Try,

```
int longestWordIndex = Array.IndexOf(words, word);
Console.WriteLine($"Index of Longest word = {longestWordIndex}");
```

Comment: Oh, so we're thinking OP wants the position in the array and not in the original string? I guess that's possible.

Comment: Okay so, this piece of code is finding the position of the word but it is ignoring spaces and single characters, e.g, if i take input : my name is burhan, it gives the position : 3

Comment: @M.BurhanAhmad Yes, Prasad's code finds what number word it is. So if your string has three words, and the second one is the longest, it will yield 1 (as 0 is the first word, 1 is the second, 2 is the third). It's another valid interpretation of what you're asking for in your question.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar your answer worked just fine! Thankyou so much!

Answer (score 1):

Validation of punctuation and other characters aside:

```
const string sentence = "Find the position of the longest word in this sentence";

var longestWord =
   sentence
      .Split(' ')
      .OrderByDescending(w => w.Length)
      .First();

var position = sentence.IndexOf(longestWord, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

In *general case*, we should come to terms: what *word* is. If we agree that

> Word is a non-empty sequence of letters and apostrophes

we can *match* words with a help of *regular expessions* and then *query* matches to obtain the longest one with a help of *Linq*.
Please, note, that in *general case* (with punctuations) `Split` is not enough.

**Code:**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string line = 
  "This is the sentence; it has some punctuations! ---note-it's-not-the-longest--";

var result = Regex
  .Matches(line, @"[\p{L}']+")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .MaxBy(match => match.Value.Length);

Console.Write(
  $"Word is \"{result.Value}\" at postion {result.Index} (length {result.Length})"
);
```

**Outcome:**

```
Word is "punctuations" at postion 34 (length 12)
```